# Configure FTP Publishing on IIS 7.5

Tags: ftp, iis-7.5, web

I have a server that is hosting multiple websites. I want users to be able to access their sites using FTP all running on port 21. Is this possible in IIS 7.5 (wont surprise me if it isnt!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes  you can  install and configure  some ftp server .   And after  you make that  you can add user and pass  for some  hosting client .  After that he will have  access  to hiss folder

This is good tutorial

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Creating-Configuring-FTP.html

Answer (score 1):

In IIS7.5 there's lots of new stuff around FTP, for example FTPS (ftp + SSL), and if you are hosting multiple sites and if you already have specific users for each site, you can try implementing User isolation, and you can find greate tutorials on:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/356/ftp-7-for-iis-7/

Answer (score -1):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

Microsoft have continued their downward spiral with the "form over function" IIS 7.5 in which they've tried another half hearted attempt at extending IIS FTP capability.

In short, the above can be achieved but in an embarassing way!

1. Make sure you have the FTP options
   for IIS installed (Windows
   Components)
2. Right click your web
   site and choose `Add FTP Publishing`
3. Make sure you tick `Enable Virtual
   Host Names` and enter the site
   address there e.g. www.example.com
4. Continue as necessary

Now, the "special" part

When setting up your FTP client, **you must make sure the username is** `<website address>|<username>` e.g. www.example.com|jimbo

Comment: That's just one way to do it. You can also use user isolation to do it from a single, central FTP service as the answer from user61995 has noted. Your little "form over function" rant is actually contradicted by the content of your rant - which suggests that they've actually implemented *more function* at the (according to you) expense of form.